# Input url of photo in textbox and show it at picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I would like to ask is there any possible way to input url in textbox and after pressing " submit " button and it will show at picturebox or something else , I've seen it doable in visual studio but not in c# does anyone have any ideas regarding this?

Comment: use the paint event of the picturbox to draw the text.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing? You have an idea, implement it. PictureBox has ImageLocation-property you can use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do draw the text using the `pictureBox1_Paint` event

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Font yourFont = new Font("Arial", 12))
    {
        if (textBox1.Text != null)
        {
            string yourtext = textBox1.Text;

            e.Graphics.DrawString(yourtext, yourFont, Brushes.Red, new Point(5, 5));

            this.Refresh();  //add this in your button click event if you want to perform it on a click event instead.
        }
    }
}
```

[image: !btn]

or, if you want to do this using a button click, then add this line `this.Refresh();` on your `button_Click` event rather than applying directly in your `pictureBox1_Paint` event.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{            
    this.Refresh();
}
```

[image: btn_click]

---

*As per your new query...*

If you just want to display your image URL in the picturebox by just entering the URL in the textbox on a button click, then try:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = textBox1.Text;
    pictureBox1.ImageLocation = str;
}
```

Alternatively, for displaying the image in the picturebox, use:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string str = textBox1.Text;
    Image img = Image.FromFile(str);
    pictureBox1.Image = img;
}
```

Comment: @TeekaaySevenKnights use the namespace above `System.Drawing`

Comment: Can i ask whats the extentions for e.Graphics.DrawString?

Comment: It doesn't work , it still shows Error 2 'System.EventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Graphics' and no extension method 'Graphics' accepting a first argument of type 'System.EventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\Lab\Desktop\OFFICAL STAC\StacProductions\StacProductions\Lists of Clothing Forms\Men's Clothing.cs 38 27 StacProductions

Comment: @TeekaaySevenKnights call this on your `pacturebox1_paint` event

Comment: If you're trying to display the picture available on a website accessible using url you can use WebClient object and download the picture on your local drive and display it in picture box. If you are trying to display text typed in text box as image then above code is fine. I'm not sure if ImageLocation can pull the image from a web url. If it can then no need to do what I have mentioned initially. Just use ImageLocation property as mentioned by @M. Raees.

Comment: As in i would like to imput like from your own folder : C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures into the textbox and it will display on picture box after pressing " submit " after imputing pictureBox.ImageLocation = textBox.Text; ---> It showes error :  private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e) { throw new System.NotImplementedException(); } –

Comment: @TeekaaySevenKnights see my edits..if this is what you are trying to say?

Comment: @Rakitić I'm asking like if i were to input a photo from my folder C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures then after pressing " submit " It will display the photo in the picturebox , Thats what i mean

Comment: Tried it , It works just have to set some size re-sizing , thanks everyone !

Comment: @TeekaaySevenKnights the appropriate response would be to mark the answer solved if it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

On the click event of the submit button add the following code

```
pictureBox.ImageLocation = textBox.Text;
```

Comment: After adding it , When submit is pressed along with the codes Raktic gave , it shows a error in dev form :

Comment: More of focused part is this :      private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new System.NotImplementedException();
        }

Comment: The error basically means that the pictureBox1_Click event hasn't been coded. If the URL is correct then the above code will work if added in the event of the Submit button without the need to add further code. Click on the Submit button on design view -> properties -> Events -> (Double click on) Click and it will take you to the Click event of the button add the code there.

Comment: Furthermore, if not needed don't call the pictureBox click event. If needed then code it. One way to stop calling is to go to Design view -> PictureBox Properties -> Events -> Delete the entire text from the click event.

Comment: Can i ask the code above used is url from C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures or is it url from the web? Both it shows " X " When it's pressed submitted and when u click on the " X "  the error shows up

Comment: I removed everything and imput that , it still shows " X " Redirecting to the same error that it's not implemented

Comment: Both. Make sure you replace pictureBox and textBox in the above code with the name of the pictureBox and textBox that you have.

Comment: Already did , It still show " X " On the picturebox tho , Anyways what format is this? url or is it C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures ?